# Document storage / searching

Tags: c#, pdf, full-text-indexing

I am hoping you can point me in the direction of the correct technologies. I am part of a small software development team that have good skills in c# development and SQL databases.

We have been tasked with writing a document storage application. This application would receive a scanned document in PDF format. We need to store the document and offer the operator the ability to search through stored docs. This search would need to include the ability to search the text inside the PDF.

For example if we had a database with lots of PDFs about animals we would need the operator to search via the keyword "horse" and be given a list of all the docs that mention the word "horse".

I have been reading about NoSQL databases and library such as Lucene.Net. But I have now invested a lot of time and am still not clear what technologies I should be using. Has anyone got any experience in something similar or have an idea of the direction I should be heading?

Comment: What kind of volume for the PDF's are you talking about?

Comment: @scalabl3 Just turn it up to 11; you'll be OK with the volume then!

Comment: I think NoSQL is a distraction here. Just use a full-text system such as Lucene or Solr. It's probably best you try a few (they'll take a few hours each to set up) and see what technology your team likes. If you choose an established one, they'll all be good - especially with (relatively) small numbers of files.

Comment: I have almost EXACT same requirements as you. I'm a little bit disappointed to see such question get closed down on stackoverflow. I'll be interested to know what technology or solutions you have choose finally.